# Android Spinner not working on Samsung Devices with Android 5.0

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm using a custom Spinner widget with the code below.
Everything works fine on most devices except on Samsung's devices with Android 5.0. On click the Spinner should display a list of values but that doesn't happen.
On emulators and others brands devices with Android 5.0 it works fine.

Has anyone faced a similiar isse or have any idea of what might be happening?

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/_combo_spinner"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cell_text_section_text_padding_bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cell_text_section_text_padding_left"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/cell_text_section_text_padding_right"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/cell_text_section_text_padding_top"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

<View
    android:layout_width="@dimen/drawable_stroke_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@color/stroke_dark_grey"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cell_text_section_text_padding_bottom"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/cell_text_section_text_padding_top" />

<ImageView
    style="@style/image__default"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cell_text_section_text_padding_left"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cell_text_section_text_padding_right"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_expand" />
```

Java

```
public class ComboBoxView extends LinearLayout {

private Spinner mSpinner;
private OnItemSelectedListener mListener;

public ComboBoxView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initializeLayout(context);
}

public ComboBoxView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initializeLayout(context);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public ComboBoxView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initializeLayout(context);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public ComboBoxView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    initializeLayout(context);
}

// Internal methods:

/**
 * Initializes the layout
 *
 * @param context
 */
private void initializeLayout(final Context context) {

    mListener = null;

    // Inflate and retrieve the views:
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_combo_box, this);
    mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id._combo_spinner);

    // Finish initialization:
    final int paddingTop = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_text_section_text_padding_top);
    final int paddingBottom = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_text_section_text_padding_bottom);
    final int paddingLeft = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_text_section_text_padding_left);
    final int paddingRight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cell_text_section_text_padding_right);
    setOnClickListener(onClick);
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_primary);
    setClickable(true);
    setPadding(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return true;
}

private final OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSpinner.performClick();
    }
};

@Override
public void clearFocus() {
    super.clearFocus();
    mSpinner.clearFocus();
}

// External methods:

/**
 * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when
 * an item in this view has been selected (extracted from {@link AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener}).
 */
public interface OnItemSelectedListener {

    /**
     * <p>Callback method to be invoked when an item in this view has been
     * selected. This callback is invoked only when the newly selected
     * position is different from the previously selected position or if
     * there was no selected item.</p>
     * <p/>
     * Impelmenters can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the
     * data associated with the selected item.
     *
     * @param parent   The ComboBoxView where the selection happened
     * @param position The position of the view in the adapter
     * @param id       The row id of the item that is selected
     */
    void onItemSelected(ComboBoxView parent, int position, long id);

    /**
     * Callback method to be invoked when the selection disappears from this
     * view. The selection can disappear for instance when touch is activated
     * or when the adapter becomes empty.
     *
     * @param parent The ComboBoxView that now contains no selected item.
     */
    void onNothingSelected(ComboBoxView parent);
}

public void setValuesAsString(final List<String> newValues) {
    setValuesAsString(newValues, 0);
}

public void setValuesAsString(final List<String> newValues, int initialValue) {

    List<CharSequence> result = new ArrayList<CharSequence>(newValues.size());
    for(String value : newValues) {
        result.add(value);
    }
    setValues(result, initialValue);
}

public void setValues(final List<CharSequence> newValues) {
    setValues(newValues, 0);
}

public void setValues(final List<CharSequence> newValues, int initialValue) {

    if((initialValue >= newValues.size()) || (initialValue < -1)) {
        IllegalArgumentException ex = new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for initialValue");
        LOG.error(LOG.SOURCE.UI, "Invalid",ex);
        throw ex;
    }

    // Prepare the list of elements:
    // NOTE: The last item in ComboBoxArrayAdapter must be empty. Items should also contain the
    // same number of lines as the "tallest" entry:
    final List<CharSequence> finalValues = new ArrayList<CharSequence>(newValues.size());
    finalValues.addAll(newValues);

    int maxLines = 1;
    for(CharSequence text : newValues) {
        final String[] lines = text.toString().split("\r\n|\r|\n");
        maxLines = Math.max(maxLines, lines.length);
    }
    finalValues.add("");

    // Prepare spinner:
    final ComboBoxArrayAdapter adapter = new ComboBoxArrayAdapter(this.getContext(), R.layout.view_combo_box_item, finalValues);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.view_combo_box_item_dropdown);
    adapter.setMaxLines(maxLines);
    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        boolean firstSelection = true;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                int index = (position >= (mSpinner.getCount() - 1)) ? -1 : position;
                mListener.onItemSelected(ComboBoxView.this, index, id);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onNothingSelected(ComboBoxView.this);
            }
        }
    });

    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onNothingSelected(this);
    }

    // Set initial selection:
    if(initialValue != -1) {
        mSpinner.setSelection(initialValue);
    } else {
        mSpinner.setSelection(newValues.size());
    }
}


public void setOnItemSelectedListener(final OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}


public int getSelectedItem() {
    int result = mSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    if(result >= mSpinner.getCount()) {
        result = -1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Spinner
[image]

Example Result
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the spinner opening its list with no items in it on click over the spinner?

Comment: The spinner has a list of items. It also animates on click and the logcat displays the following:

`ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN`.

But then nothing happens.

Comment: Does it work on other phone brands running Lollipop other than Samsung?

Comment: Yes it does. It works on a Sony. I also tried to set up an emulator with the same specs as the Samsung with Android 5.0 and Android 5.1 and it works. Someone told me that it might be a TouchWiz thing but I haven't the time yet to prove that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally fixed this!
The android property `clickable` was set to `false`, but the click behaviour was performed in the ComboBoxView.java file on the following code:

```
private final OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         mSpinner.performClick();
    }
};
```

This was working everywhere (devices and emulators) except on Samsung devices with Android 5.0. This I couldn't figure out why.

After I changed the `cliclabke` property to true it started working.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Thanks.

Comment: removing android:clickable="false" worked for me.  Not sure setting the click listener is correct.